# Returns tuples of books that have a "keyword" in common

Tags: python-2.7

I have a database saved as a list of tuples, and every tuple has 4 elements. The first element is the book's number, the second element is the book's name, the third element is the book's author, and the forth element is the book’s publishing year.

I need a function called `findBook(L, keyword)`, that receives the books as a list of tuples, `keyword` as a string, and returns all the `tuples of books` that have `keyword` in them.
The `tuple of the book` should be like this:

```
(BookNumber, BookName, Author, YearPublished)
```

How to write a search engine that will help us find these certain books?

I've tried to start with this, but it isn't working:

```
def findBook(L,keyword):

    for i in L:
        BookNumber=i[0]
        BookName=i[1]
        Author=i[2]
        YearPublished=i[3]
        i=(BookNumber,BookName,Author,YearPublished)

        if keyword == str(BookName) or keyword==BookNumber or keyword==str(Author) or keyword==str(YearPublished):
            return i
```

so if i have a harry potter book , and i enter the keyword : "harry" it should return all the whole tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate over the entries that may have the `keyword` you're looking for, grouping them into a list, that shall be returned by the end of the process:

```
def findBook(L, keyword):

    books = list()
    for book in L:

        book = tuple(entry for entry in book)
        if [i for i in book if str(i).find(keyword) != -1]:
            books.append(book)

    return books

L = [(2,"harry potter and the prisoner of azkaban ","J.K Rowling","1998"),
        (3,"harry potter and the half blood prince","J.K Rowling","2007"),
        (6,"Harry potter and deathly hallows","J.K Rowling","2010"),
        (8,"The secret","someone","2009")]

print findBook(L, "harry")
```

Output:

```
[(2, 'harry potter and the prisoner of azkaban ', 'J.K Rowling', '1998'), (3, 'harry potter and the half blood prince', 'J.K Rowling', '2007')]
```

Notice the third entry was not found because the `keyword` is "harry" and not "Harry", to do insensitive case search, use:

```
def findBook(L, keyword):

    books = list()
    keyword = keyword.tolower()

    for book in L:

        book = tuple(entry for entry in book)
        if [i for i in book if str(i).tolower().find(keyword) != -1]:
            books.append(book)

    return books
```

Comment: it keeps telling me that L is not defined .

Comment: you need to pass the information to the parameters; the call must be something like: `findBook(library_with_books, "word")`. How are you trying to call the function?

Comment: i have to write a list of 20 books at least ,and use words that are from the books' titles.

Comment: add an edit to your question with the list of books you have, and showing how you're trying to call the function `findBook()`; if you don't say what you're problem is, there's no way we can help you out

Comment: it always returns an empty list.

Comment: >>> findBook(L,"harry")
[]

Comment: you only need to call `findBook(L, "harry")`, without the `[]`; now, what is the content of `L`?

Comment: i only call findBook(L,"harry") ,the [] is the return. i just wrote a sample to test it : L=[(2,"harry potter and the prisoner of azkaban ","J.K Rowling","1998"),(3,"harry potter and the half blood prince","J.K Rowling","2007"),(6,"Harry potter and deathly hallows","J.K Rowling","2010"),(8,"The secret","someone","2009")]

Comment: You have to use the second comparison line, then, as I've written in the answer. I'll re-edit to make it even more clear. Does it work using the second snippet?

Comment: Mr user. Perhaps you should start at the beginning? Go here and do the tutorials in order then you'll realise why "L is not defined" is absurd. http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/

Comment: thank you Paul ,but i don't need this .it was only that i forgot to define it before the function.

Comment: @user1924912 I had not tested the code, and now I've noticed it actually wasn't right; please, check my edit.

Comment: @user1924912 if you consider this answer is what you were expecting, please, accept it as an answer, click on the tick mark right below the voting arrows, and your post will be marked as answered.